# query find where element in array

Tags: mongodb

my documents "parents" got the folowing structure:

```
{childrenIdList: [23, 24, 34]}
{childrenIdList: [23, 88]}
{childrenIdList: [1, 5, 8]}
```

how to select parents by `childId` in there childrenIdList?

Such query must return first two documents of 3 in my example if `childId = 23`.

I tried to use [elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) method, but seemingly it works only with objects, i.e. it would work only if my data would be     `{childrenIdList: [{Id: 1}, {Id: 5}, {Id: 8}]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `db.collection.find({childrenIdList: 23})`. See the [Query Arrays](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-arrays) section in the manual for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find({"parent.childrenIdList": {$in: [23]}})
```

Comment: Can you expand this answer to explain why this works?